How to get a file's name without its extension or to load the entire path with the file without the file's extension?
I have the following following String Array:
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

pathName = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('Python file','*.py')])

Output
#pathName = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\my_program.py  

Is there a way to extract the name of my file? In this example I would want the output to be "my_program"
Or a better solution for me would be to load directly file path without the file's extension. I need ti pathName to be 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\my_program'
I tried using tkinter's fd.askopenfilename but it always gets the file extension too.

the simplest: use path.rsplit('.', 1)[0] to split on last . and get first element. But Python has also special functions for this which can be better (safer)

using p = pathlib.Path(pathName) you can use special functions to get some parts.

as I know all dialog windows in all GUIs don't have function to get it without path because it is not task for dialog window.

You can use pathlib.Path() to work with path
import pathlib 

p = pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\my_program.py')

print( p.stem )    # 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\my_program'
print( p.parent )  # 'C:\Users\User\Desktop'
print( p.suffix )  # '.py'

you can also use / to create new path
print( p.parent / 'subfolder' / 'new.py' )  
# 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\subfolder\new.py'

Doc: pathlib

It works! I manage to make it work! Thank you, you beautiful people!


Is there a way to extract the name of my file?

You might use os.path.splitext for that purpose
import os
filename = "file.txt"
name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
print(name)  # file
print(ext)  # .txt


Is there a way to get the dir path too? of the file from the pathName after I used askopenfilename? In my example should be C:\Users\User\Desktop

I manage to make it work! Thank you!

you can use os.path.dirname(path) to get C:\Users\User\Desktop and os.path.basename(path) to get my_program.py
